# Upload file with content type as application/octet-stream in java?

Tags: java, file-upload

I have to upload file to server whose API is a PUT request of content type as `application/octet-stream`. Below is my code

```
private void uploadVideo(File binaryFile, String url) {
    try {
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPut put = new HttpPut(url);
        FileEntity reqEntity = new FileEntity(binaryFile, "application/octet-stream");
        reqEntity.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
        put.setEntity(reqEntity);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(put);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        Log.d("INFO", "rcode:" + response.getStatusLine().toString());
        if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() - 200 >= 100)
            throw new Exception("bad status code: " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I keep getting bad request but when I try from postman the file uploads perfectly fine. Any solutions?

```
 bad status code: 400
```

Comment: Could you please update us with the exact error code and message you are getting in response?

Comment: Try using `FileEntity reqEntity = new FileEntity(binaryFile, ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);` FileEntity(File, String) is deprecated. Also remove `reqEntity.setContentType("application/octet-stream");` from your code

Comment: @Shravan40 i get 400 status code